# Python - How to copy content of USB(Flash) to system directory

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shutil

What i want to program is,

When **USB drive** is connected to system the code must initiate automatically and **Copy** the content(**Directories, Files etc.**) of usb drive to Default Backup Directory of **System**.

I have came across some sites and found that I can use **shutil library** https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html
High-level file operations. I haven't used Shutil Library, So is there any other way to achieve,

has anyone did this before so please help. Thanks

Comment: Copying off of a flash drive isn't likely to be any different from copying from anywhere else. Do you understand how to copy any files, with `shutil` or anything else? Where the flash drive's filesystem shows up will probably vary depending on your OS, but once you know that part, there's not much to it.

Comment: This is a good project: https://github.com/bestmahdi2/FileStealerUSB2PC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fix this and solved, hope this will help to those guys who are beginners like me.

First i code to copy files and directories using shutil for more help https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html,
connect usb drive to perform operation

Step 1 : ***code_to_copy.py***

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns

files = os.listdir('/media/user/')

destination = '/home/user/Path/Backup/back_%s'%datetime.datetime.now()
try :
    for f in files:
        source = '/media/user/%s' % f
        copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', 'tmp*'))    
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

you can run this file to check whether it is copying or not, then

create bash file

Step 2 : ***code_to_copy.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home/user/path/code_to_copy.py
```

make sure you have permissions to this files

step 3 : **add to cron**

```
$ crontab -e

#add this line
* * * * * /home/user/path/code_to_copy.sh > /tmp/code_to_copy.log
```

**# check log file at /tmp/code_to_copy.log**

after a minute your connected device data will be copied to your backup folder and hola.

Comment: how are you ensuring that the USB drives are always mounted to /media/user/

Answer (score 3):

You can use pythons shutil library which is pretty simple to handle copy operations.If you need to automate the process try the below steps:

1:If getting all files in a pendrive or any other removable drive get all the files and write it into a list by following way:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('path-to-removable-media')
```

2:once thats done iterate through list and use shutil library for copying files.

```
 import shutil
 for f in files:
     shutil.copyfile('/source path/%s' % f, '/destination path/%s' %f)
```

3:Now if you need to automate the process create a bash file(file with extension sh) with following content in your folder where python script is present.(ex:create file test.sh and copy following)

```
 #!/bin/bash
 clear
 python script.py
```

4:Then add this in your cronjob if you need to check or run in specificintervals and if removable media is not connected exception case need to be also handled.

5:For getting source you can make use of subprocess in python.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen("lsblk", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for out in output.communicate()[0].split():
    if '/media/' in out:
        print out
```

This will give path of removable media in linux devices.

Comment: Hey @vishnu This helps me but how to get source path of flash drive?

Comment: @KamleshJaiswal i have anwser for detecting remavable media

Comment: But this method of detecting the removable media requires someone to look at the printed lines.  How can the print result be taken automatically?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example how to copy a file to USB(removable device) you can do invert.

```
import os
file = "cat.jpg"
os.system("for /F \"tokens=1*\" %a in (\'fsutil fsinfo drives\') do (for %c in (%b) do (for /F \"tokens=3\" %d in (\'fsutil fsinfo drivetype %c\') do (if %d equ Removable (copy " + file + " %c))))")
```

Comment: Can you explain what all the stuff in this really long line of code does?